# 'in' operator does not work with tuples and sets in python

Tags: python, set

If I have two identical tuples:

```
>>> e = ('a', 1)
>>> c = ('a', 1)
>>> e == c
True
>>> hash(e)
9135824190991152417
>>> hash(c)
9135824190991152417
```

but to my surprise:

```
>>> se = set(c)
>>> e in se
False
```

how can I use a set to check if a tuple is in it?

Comment: Verify that all value from `e` are in `se` ?

Comment: Did you print ``se``? It doesn't contain the tuple, only its items.

Comment: `e = ('a', 1)` is not in `set('a', 1)` (or `{1, 'a'}`) indeed...

Comment: dammit you are right guys, so how do I make a set of tuples?

Comment: the constructor expects an iterable... so wrap the element in another tuple: `set((c,))`. or: `se = set(); se.add(c)`.

Comment: ``set`` takes an iterable from which its content is taken. Use a literal ``{c}`` or wrapped ``set((c,))`` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see, `e` is NOT an element of `se`, so `in` returns false

```
se = {'a', 1}
e = ('a', 1)
```

As [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set) takes an iterable, and uses its values to populate its structure, you can't pass your tuple like this, use the `{}` syntax, or give a list (or tuple) that containes your tuple

```
# {('a', 1)}
se = {c} 
se = set((c,)) 
se = set([c])
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example `se = {'a', 1}` not `{('a',1)}` and hence you get false. To create a set of tuples as which I think you want, use either `set([c,])` or `{c}`